# Draw on a windows program

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Ok so here it is: 
I'm making a basic pong game for school, and I can get anything set up. But after the intialisation (start) of the program I can't seem to update the window. I've tried drawing a backbuffer first and yet it doesn't do anything. code is under here so have a look pretty please and thank you in advance!!

```
//=============================================================================
//Seth Dark @2011
//Pong v1.0
//=============================================================================

//=============================================================================
//to do list
// - get the ball moving
// - figure out the AI
// - figure out the ball vs paddle
// Version 2
// - count time or points
// - hiscore bord
//=============================================================================

// Pong.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Resource.h"

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                     // current instance
TCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];       // The title bar text
TCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING]; // the main window class name
BackBuffer* gBackBuffer = 0;         // The backbuffer we will render

HDC    hdc;                          // ------------------------------ gamble

const int gClientWidth = 800;
const int gClientHeight = 600;

Vec2 playerPos(20.0f, 250.0f);
Vec2 aiPos(780.0f,250.0f);
Vec2 ballPos(400.0f, 250.0f);

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM             MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL             InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

//---------------------------------------------
//INT RUN
//---------------------------------------------
int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
    int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Place code here.
    HDC bbDC = gBackBuffer->getDC();
    //Clear backbuffer
    HBRUSH oldBrush = (HBRUSH)SelectObject(bbDC, GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH));
    Rectangle(bbDC,0 ,0 ,800, 600);

    //Draw player
    SelectObject(hdc,GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH)); // drawing the thing
    Rectangle(bbDC,
        (int)playerPos.x -10,
        (int)playerPos.y - 50,
        (int)playerPos.x + 10,
        (int)playerPos.y + 50); 

    MSG msg;
    HACCEL hAccelTable;

    // Initialize global strings
    LoadString(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadString(hInstance, IDC_PONG, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_PONG));

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}

//
//  FUNCTION: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  PURPOSE: Registers the window class.
//
//  COMMENTS:
//
//    This function and its usage are only necessary if you want this code
//    to be compatible with Win32 systems prior to the 'RegisterClassEx'
//    function that was added to Windows 95. It is important to call this function
//    so that the application will get 'well formed' small icons associated
//    with it.
//      Creation of the window upon wich we will draw
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra    = 20;
    wcex.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon         = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_PONG));
    wcex.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.lpszMenuName  = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_PONG);
    wcex.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject (BLACK_BRUSH);

    return RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
}

BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hWnd;

    hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

    hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
    CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, 819, 600, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if (!hWnd)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
        wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
        // Parse the menu selections:
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case IDM_ABOUT:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        break;

    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        // TODO: Add any drawing code here...

        //Draw player rectangle get class look page 237 - 
        SelectObject(hdc,GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH));
        Rectangle(hdc,
            (int)playerPos.x -10,
            (int)playerPos.y - 50,
            (int)playerPos.x + 10,
            (int)playerPos.y + 50); 

        //Draw AI rectangle get class look page 237 - AI
        Rectangle(hdc,
            (int)aiPos.x -10,
            (int)aiPos.y - 50,
            (int)aiPos.x + 10,
            (int)aiPos.y + 50);  

        //Draw the ball 
        Ellipse(hdc,
            (int)ballPos.x -20,
            (int)ballPos.y - 20,
            (int)ballPos.x + 20,
            (int)ballPos.y + 20);

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;

    case WM_KEYDOWN:
    {
        switch(wParam)
        {
        case 'Z':
            playerPos.y -= 5;
            break;
        case 'S':
            playerPos.y += 5;
            break;
        }

        // up, down, enter to play or restart

        break;
        return 0;
    }

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

I hope this is enough info! this thing is driving me crazy since sunday. Any help why I can't draw would be appriciated, I've tried putting it in the run and the drawing and a couple of other things

Comment: Yeuch! You couldn't have done without pasting the whole program? Is there any particular reason this has the `c++` tag? I haven't closely looked at that code, but what I've seen looks like C to me.

Comment: @sbi : VC++ doesn't support C99 and this code declares objects beyond the beginning of functions, so it's *technically* C++ ;-]

Comment: sbi, this isn't a fifth of the whole program, it doesn't include any cpp or h files. yet this part was neccasry for the complete picture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WM_PAINT` is sent to a window whenever it's area needs to be updated.
When you press a key, you only update objects state.

You can either copy `WM_PAINT` code in a separate function and call it when a key is pressed or
call [RedrawWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which will send paint messages.

Comment: `Invalidate` would work too, and it's a little more graceful because you won't get more than one WM_PAINT when the updates come too fast.

Comment: @Mark, thanks. @Seth: check out also [Invalidating the Client Area](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145005(v=vs.85).aspx)